# Were any prominent people exiled from France during the Hundred years war? Especially between 1390-1397

Tags: middle-ages, england, france, scotland, hundred-years-war

Were any notable figures (such as noblemen, or mercenaries, politician [idk what they called them back then] etc. ) that were exiled from France during Hundred Years War between 1390 to 1397. Or any conspiring forces that worked against Charles VI [that took refuge in Scotland or nearby areas even England but its not necessary I just wanna know if any "anti-French"]  in the same period?

Edit:  While I was aware that France was divided into different feudal states i thought they all were consolidated under the rule of the French king during the war with England. but as some of you pointed out that there was no concept of France as we know it today so i deeply apologize for my ignorance as I'm not native to Europe. When i say France i mean the land under the Kingship of Charles VI or any other state that helped them during the Hundred years war. when i referred "anti_French" i meant the same- Forces that conspired against Charles VI

So far I have consulted Wiki and Extra Credits YT channel. But nothing answers the specific this question. I'm new to Stack overflow so please forgive my lack of understanding of rules and laws here.

Comment: "France" at the time was a patchwork of feudal entities. What would an enemy of France even mean? And why would they go to Sweden?

Comment: What is your definition of "France" during the 100-years war??

Comment: @MoisheKohan  Sorry for being ignorant I have very less Idea about that time period as I'm not from EU. While I was aware that France was divided into different feudal states i thought they all were consolidated under the rule of the French king during the war with England.

Comment: @Alex as i said i am very limited in my pov about Europe in middle ages if you would ask me to define "France" i would say every geographical area of present day France that fought against the English in 100 yrs war.

Comment: @MCW So far I have consulted Wiki and Extra Credits YT channel

Comment: @HarshitJaiswal - In H:SE, we try to make sure that the question contains all you know, so that people don't have to read a long comment string to understand the question. I've copied your comments into the your question - please feel free to edit further and to flag any comments for deletion if they are no longer needed.    Welcome to the site.

Comment: Then you should say explicitly "enemies of the King of France" in your post (make an edit rather than a comment). But I still do not understand why would anybody escape from France to Sweden: It is much further away than other places in the territory of the Holy Roman Empire or even Brittany: Currently, Brittany is a province in France but back then, it was an independent duchy; the second Treaty of Guérande (1381) established Brittany's neutrality in the Anglo-French conflict.

Comment: @HarshitJaiswal - Might be worth revising the question based on [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hundred_Years'_War#Second_peace:_1389%E2%80%931415) or [map2](https://external-preview.redd.it/e67nToQ1tsH6ovYrMx86vqZ_g-peU1t3HNPnY2CqChw.jpg?auto=webp&s=7d8bd6db186b7604c831ce71ea00496fdf98f09e) or [map3](https://www.themaparchive.com/product/the-hundred-years-war/).  Given that there are  multiple requests to define "France". Also worth noting that the two nations appear to be at  peace in the period you describe.

Comment: During the 100 years war, the English would be full of enemies of the kings of France

Comment: @MoisheKohan yeah I don't know why I wrote that maybe because I wanted to know if anyone fled to The north western Eu.